# Display a list of items in Ember not working with each

Tags: html, loops, templates, ember.js

I am trying to display a list of items in Ember.js but is not working and I don't get any error in the console. If I go to a specific element it works but I can't iterate the array.

```
  <h1> Forecast 16 days </h1>

  // this line works
  {{model.[0].clouds}}

  // this block doesn't work
  {{#each item as |model|}}
     <div>{{item.clouds}}</div>
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: Why negative? You can't ask stupid questions in stackoverflow?

Comment: Ask new questions. Never give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` block params are inverted. It should be

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
    <div>{{item.clouds}}</div>
{{/each}}
```